# FTP upload file The requested FTP command is not supported when using HTTP proxy

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

Can someone please take a look at the code below and tell me what I am doing wrong. I am just going in circles,,, any pointers greatly appreciated

```
public class FtpWebRequestUtil
{
    private static string RemoteHost;
    private static string RemoteFtpPath;
    public static NetworkCredential Credential = new NetworkCredential();

    public FtpWebRequestUtil()
    {
    }

    public FtpWebRequestUtil(string RemoteAddress, string RemotePath, string RemoteUser, string RemotePwd)
    {
        Credential.UserName = RemoteUser;
        Credential.Password = RemotePwd;
        RemoteHost = RemoteAddress;
        RemoteFtpPath = RemotePath;
    } 

    public string UploadFile(string localFilePath)
    {
        int startTime = Environment.TickCount;
       // Console.WriteLine("Uploading File " + localFilePath);
        try
        {
            FileInfo localFile = new FileInfo(localFilePath); //e.g.: c:\\Test.txt
            byte[] buf = new byte[2048];
            int iWork;
            string remoteFile = "ftp://" + RemoteHost + "/" + RemoteFtpPath + "/" + localFile.Name;

            FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest) FtpWebRequest.Create(remoteFile);
           // req.Proxy = 

            req.Credentials = Credential;


           // FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWe

            req.UseBinary = true;
            req.KeepAlive = true;
            req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            StreamWriter myStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
            myStreamWriter.Write(new StreamReader("TestFiles\\" + localFile.Name).ReadToEnd());
            myStreamWriter.Close();
            FtpWebResponse myFtpWebResponse = (FtpWebResponse) req.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status: " + myFtpWebResponse.StatusDescription);

            myFtpWebResponse.Close();
            return "SUCCESS";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There was an error connecting to the FTP Server.");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Time taken for downloading file is " + (Environment.TickCount - startTime).ToString());
        return "FAILURE";
    }


    ************************                       *********************************
    FtpWebRequestUtil ftpClient = new FtpWebRequestUtil(FtpUrl, InputFolder, FtpUser, FtpPassword);
    try
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        ftpClient.UploadFile(UploadingFileName);
                }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Assert.Fail(exception.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            ftpClient = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ftp command not supported when using http proxy

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
req.Proxy = new WebProxy(); // initialize this FtpWebRequest property
```

Comment: ok tried it,, now getting object reference not set to an instance ):

Comment: where did you add this line of code? post the code with the changes

Comment: req.Proxy = new WebProxy();
                req.Proxy = null;
                req.Credentials = Credential;
               // FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWe

                req.UseBinary = true;
 req.UsePassive = true;
 req.KeepAlive = true;
 StreamWriter myStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());

Comment: its not letting to post the full code because of character limitation

Comment: you could have edited the code in your post itself. Anyways -  remove req.Proxy = null; and where do you get this object ref error? you must have not initialized an object before you used it

Comment: StreamWriter myStreamWriter = newStreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());

Comment: then definitely there is an error with 'remoteFile' . check if its right,

Comment: let me chk,, when u say error with remote? what are you basically referring to .. I checked the remote file it looks to be alrite

Comment: `req.Proxy = new WebProxy(); req.Proxy = null; ` what's the point of 2nd statement?

Answer (score 8):

It turns out that only the `RETR`, `LIST`, and `NLST` methods are supported by `System.Net.FtpWebRequest` when a `HTTP` proxy is configured and it doesn't matter that you are not setting a proxy in your code: if a `HTTP` proxy (not `FTP` proxy) is configured in the system proxy settings (in i.e. : Internet Options\Connections\LAN setting\Proxy Server\ Use a proxy server for your LAN), then you will get this error when trying to upload to the `FTP` server.

The workaround is use IE to change the system settings to switch off the use of the `HTTP` proxy. However if you have access to the affected code the solution is to set the `Proxy` property of the request to null, for example:

```
request.Proxy = null;
```

Comment: Should be correct answer, +1 for the explanation too.

Answer (score 0):

The exceptions itself is the answer - it is not supported. Probably you have some HTTP proxy that is preventing direct connection to FTP. According to [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx), if the specified proxy is an HTTP proxy, only the DownloadFile, ListDirectory, and ListDirectoryDetails commands are supported - so UploadFile is not.